# FieldQuotes on all properties

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

Is there an attribute like FieldQuotes that I can apply to properties?

Also, is it possible to add FieldQuotes to all fields automatically so that I don't have to define it for each and every field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute you are looking for is `FieldQuoted`. The documentation is [here](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/FileHelpers.FieldQuotedAttribute.html).

Some examples:

```
[FieldQuoted()] // Quoted with "
public string CustomerName

[FieldQuoted('[')] // Quoted between [brackets]
public string CustomerName

[FieldQuoted('"', QuoteMode.OptionalForBoth)] // Optional quoted when read or write
public string CustomerName

[FieldQuoted('"', MultilineMode.AllowForBoth)] // Indicates that the quoted string can span multiple lines
public string CustomerName
```

You do need to apply to every field.

Comment: I can't apply that to a property though.

Comment: You should not be using properties in the FileHelpers classes. The best way to use FileHelpers is to think of the record class as a 'spec' for your file format. Use it to describe the file using only public fields (yes this goes against C# best practice, I know...). Once you have loaded the file into an array of `MyFileHelpersClass[]`, then you can map the values (e.g., with a `foreach`) to a more sensible class with properties, methods, additional functionality, etc.